# Way to manipulate the result of an require or import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

We are looking for a build in or recommended way to manipulate the result of the require / import method.

Our App is isomorphic. We are using a react package which renders on the client a Map but on Server its not working because its require `leaflet` instead of `leaflet-headless` (which works on server). So our dirty fix would be to tell that when the server tries to require the module `leaflet` it should instead require `leaflet-headless`.

This sounds very dirty but I dont know if is there another solution for our case.

So my question is: Is there a recommended way to solve this ? Or should we just override the require method like this:

```
// On Server only
const superRequire = require;
require = function(module) {
    if (module === 'leaflet') module = 'leaflet-headless';
    return superRequire(module);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use something like this?

```
const leaflet = require(typeof window === 'undefined' ? 'leaflet-headless' : 'leaflet')
```

Comment: Yes - I could do this. But the problem is that I am using an external package  which is doing a require('leaflet'). So I am not able to override this if I dont want to fork their project and do my own out of it.

Comment: Are you using something like Webpack? And if so, are you building different bundles for client- and server-side?

Comment: Yes I am using webpack but only build a bundle for client.

Comment: It might be tricky to solve. I found a blogpost that works around it by setting up a fake DOM server-side: https://medium.com/@pimterry/building-a-server-rendered-map-component-part-2-using-client-side-libraries-6f1bb751f31c (but perhaps your proposed solution is easier to implement, although also quite hacky).

Comment: I've found the same blog article but I tried to prevent to do it like there. But maybe I will give it a try. Just thought it could be easy to do da Server-Only override of the require / import methods. I will give it a try! Thanks